# Publish React page on github

Tags: reactjs, github-pages

I have made a simple page with React & Redux, which I want to deploy on github.

In my terminal, I write:

```
npm run build
```

Then I add

```
"homepage": "http://myusername.github.io/mynameapp",

"predeploy": "npm run build",

"deploy": "gh-pages -d build"
```

to package.json

Then I install

```
npm install --save-dev gh-pages
```

Then I go on my

```
Github repository => settings => GitHub Pages => select gh pages branch.
```

Finally, I write

```
npm run deploy
```

The page is published, but the result is pure crap. It blends old lines of code - that I actually erased ages ago - with new ones. 100% of the images are either not displayed or not even found. I've checked the build folder, everything is fine. I did add, commit and push my project to the repo before doing the build.

Any help would be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Please check on which branch you are coding make sure it is master and take a force pull from github.
Also if you want you can try delete your build folder and run deploy after that.

Comment: I am on the master branch. It is really weird.

Comment: if you can provide repository link if it is a public repo

Comment: @DoneDeal the issue I saw in your code is you are not passing relative path to your images and assets. so gh-pages instead of searching images from your repository it is searching at the baseurl. I would suggest to changes the path of images by appending a dot in front '/images'--->'./images' I am quite sure it will work.